# Assign a random order to each group

Tags: sql, sqlite, random, permutation

I want to expand each row in `TableA` into 4 rows. The result hold all the columns from `TableA` and two additional columns: `SetID` = ranging from 0 to 3 and unique when grouped by `TableA`. `Random` = a random permutation of `SetID` within the same grouping.

I use SQLite and would prefer a pure SQL solution.

Table A:

```
Description
-----------
A
B
```

Desired output:

```
Description | SetID | Random
------------|-------|-------
A           |     0 | 2
A           |     1 | 0
A           |     2 | 3
A           |     3 | 1
B           |     0 | 3
B           |     1 | 2
B           |     2 | 0
B           |     3 | 1
```

My attempt so far solves creating 4 rows for each row in `TableA` but doesn't get the permutation correctly. `wrong` will contain a random number ranging from 0 to 3. I need exactly one 0, 1, 2 and 3 for each unique value in `Description` and their order should be random.

```
SELECT
  Description,
  SetID,
  abs(random()) % 4 AS wrong
FROM
  TableA
LEFT JOIN
  TableB
ON
  1 = 1
```

Table B:

```
SetID
-----
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: To get random but unique number in grouping, see this previous [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960138/sql-random-number-that-doesnt-repeat-within-a-group). OP answers his own with randomizing row by row (storing in temp table) but limit next random to number not included in previous ones.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. That might be the solution. I'll look into it.

Comment: By the way, I see you're R-savy. No doubt you can import your table and handle this in R. Do note: SQL is a declarative special-purpose language best restricted for [DML and DDL](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php) procedures. Extending beyond may not be recommended; it is not as fluid and nuanced as general-purpose objected-oriented languages: Java, C#, VB, PHP, Python, or R.

Comment: Yes, this would be easy to do in R. I'm looking for a SQL solution because of the size of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join`

```
SELECT Description,
       SetID,
       abs(random()) % 4 AS wrong
FROM TableA
CROSS JOIN TableB
```

Comment: Thank for the tip. But that doesn't solve the problem on the random permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a solution in your specialty, R. As you know, R maintains excellent database packages, one of which is [RSQLite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf). Additionally, R can run commands via the connection without the need to import very large datasets.

Your solution is essentially a **random sampling without replacement**. Simply have R run the sampling and concatenate list items into an SQL string.

Below creates a table in the SQLite database where R sends the `CREATE TABLE` command to the SQL engine. No import or export of data. Should you need to run every four rows, run an iterative loop in a defined function that outputs the sql string. For append queries change the `CREATE TABLE AS` to `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement.

```
library(RSQLite)    

sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
conn <- dbConnect(sqlite,"C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File\\newexample.db")

# SAMPLE WITHOUT REPLACEMENT
randomnums <- as.list(sample(0:3, 4, replace=F))

# SQL CONCATENATION 
sql <- sprintf("CREATE TABLE PermutationsTable AS 
             SELECT a.Description, b.SetID, 
            (select %d from TableB WHERE TableB.SetID = b.SetID AND TableB.SetID=0
             union select %d from TableB WHERE TableB.SetID = b.SetID AND TableB.SetID=1
             union select %d from TableB WHERE TableB.SetID = b.SetID AND TableB.SetID=2
             union select %d from TableB WHERE TableB.SetID = b.SetID AND TableB.SetID=3) 
             As RandomNumber
             from TableA a, TableB b;",
                  randomnums[[1]], randomnums[[2]],
                  randomnums[[3]], randomnums[[4]])

# RUN QUERY
dbSendQuery(conn, sql)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

You will notice a nested union subquery. This is used to achieve the inline random numbers for each row. Also, to return all possible combinations from all tables, no join statements are needed, simply list tables in `FROM` clause.